# how to load data into server cache?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am developing a site. I need help to load data from database into server cache. So that i can use them without fetching them again and again.

My scenario is that using spring, hibernate framework load data into server cache on startup. Using this data create a menu for navigation dynamically.

Comment: Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable the query caching and the second level cache in your hibernate configuration file, all queries with the `SessionFactory` are automatically cached if the target entity type has the `@Cacheable` annotation. To cache custom queries, just use `setCacheable(true)` on the query object.

Manually loading data into the cache would more or less violate the principles of caching. For having faster access to specific data, you can configure RAM caches and other within your database backend. If you really want to load data into cache manually, you could do that by creating queries fetching the needed data and setting them to cacheable before.

Read more: http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-two-the-query-cache/

Hope my post helped.